# MassTransit Consumer doesn't consume service bus topic messages

Tags: masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

We are using MassTransit to produce message and write to Azure Service Bus and we have a consumer, which is written using the same package to consume the message but it is unable to consume the message.

The consumer is not getting hit in local machine as well and there are no reasons in Azure Service Bus or logs to show any kind of information or error

We tried

- upgrading the package of MassTransit.
- using UseRawJsonSerilizer() to
  the consumer configuration, which helps in hitting the consumer but
  the **message.entity** attribute becomes null, so this isn't helpful
  as well.
- UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer() as well and this also doesn't
  help in hitting the consumer.

We have configured the consumer and created the consumer properly.

we have written below part of code to ConfigureServices in Program.cs to add the service and start service bus

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<CrmCatalogCreatedEventConsumer>();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(massTransitOptions.AzureServiceBusConnectionString);
        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(LogConsumeFilter<>), context);
        ConfigureMessageType<CrmCatalogCreatedEventConsumer, ICrmCatalogCreatedEvent>(context, cfg);
    });
});
```

we have written a separate method to configure the consumer as shown below

```
private static void ConfigureMessageType<TConsumer, TMessageType>(IBusRegistrationContext context, IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator busCfg)
    where TConsumer : class, IConsumer<TMessageType>
    where TMessageType : class
{
    var topicName = GetTopicName<TMessageType>();
    busCfg.Message<TMessageType>(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SetEntityName(topicName);
    });
    busCfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("_subscriptionName", topicName, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureConsumer<TConsumer>(context);
    });
}
```

We have few other consumers for other topics, which are working fine and this one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved.
The issue was because of wrong namespaces being used consumer